# Defining a function name with underscore in Javascript under Google Chromium

Tags: javascript, syntax, chromium

**EDIT:** OK, it's my problem. There are a same name config didn't loaded. Firebug has warned me that object [name] didn't found but Chromium only show the "Type Error". Sorry for this dump question.

I've defined a function with a "tag-like" prefix and it's main name as below :

```
async_fetchRecordAll() { //do something... }
```

and if this function is called in Chromium 14.0.853 , the console will reports an error :

```
"Type Error"
```

and the arguments field in error object logged in console shows that

```
arguments : Array[2]
    0 : "fetchRecordAll"
    1 : undefined
    (...)
```

But everything is OK if I execute the code in Firefox 4. Is this naming rule conflicted with any standard ? Or the error is just caused by another browser depended behavior ?

Comment: Please provide details of how you call the function including the arguments you are passing. Also, some detail of what's in the function, at least how you use the arguments. Is the undefined argument you mention supposed to be undefined?

Comment: Aw, crap. It happens because another same name config property doesn't exist. I've solved it after I fixed that. Thanks you !

Answer (score 3):

Don't you have to use the `function` keyword?

```
function async_fetchRecordAll(){ ...}
```

(I can't think of anything else without seeing the code)

Comment: Sure. I had added that before the function name.